# Trying to plot temperature and count data on same plot using xyplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I am using the xyplot in lattice trying to make a plot that shows temperature change over time in correlation with count data.  I am not sure if ggplot2 would be better? My data is arrange like this:

```
Year (1998  1998 1999 2000 2001 2001 2002)  
Low (2.777778  8.333330  10.555556 4.444444 26.388889 15.555556 12.500000)    
Geese (2 14 10 16 7 10 15)    
State (Arkansas California California California California Florida California)
```

I am stuck at this part of the code:

```
xyplot(c(geese,low)~year,subset=state=="California", par.settings=bwtheme, auto.key=TRUE)
```

The plot has the geese and low (temperature) as the same type of point and if I add a line there is no separation between the two. Please any help for this would be awesome.

Comment: Do you want 'year' in the x axis, 'low' in one y axis and 'geese' in another y axis? What about the State information? How would you like to represent it? Can you show a similar graph to represent the desired output?

Comment: That's NOT code that will create a data object in R. And ... What is `bwtheme`? If it's from some other package, you should add code to load that package. And further ... why label a question bout xyplot with a 'ggplot2' tag?

Comment: Did you just want `xyplot(geese+low~year,subset=state=="California",auto.key=TRUE, type="b")`?

Comment: MrFlick,  that completely answered my questioned.  I had to geese+low, not c(geese,low).  Thank you so much

Comment: @MrFlick, you could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot multiple series on the same plot, use `+` rather than `c()` to specify multiple `y` values. For example

```
xyplot(geese + low ~year, subset=state=="California", auto.key=TRUE, type="b")
```

That will produce

[image]